# Use Pulumi to re-deploy AWS API Gateway when method removed

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, pulumi

I use pulumi in typescript to deploy an AWSApiGateway.

I have a couple of methods and integrations:

```js
let methodResource = new aws.apigateway.Method('method'+resourceName+method, {
        restApi: api.id,
        resourceId: resource.id,
        httpMethod: method,
        authorization: 'NONE',
    }, {
        dependsOn: [api, resource]
    });
    
let integration = new aws.apigateway.Integration('integration'+resourceName+method, {
    restApi: api.id,
    resourceId: resource.id,
    httpMethod: methodResource.httpMethod,
    integrationHttpMethod: 'POST',
    type: 'AWS_PROXY',
    uri: lambda.invokeArn,
}, {
    dependsOn: [api, resource, lambda]
});

// ...many more...
```

and I added a deployment with a trigger:

```js
// collect resource.id that should trigger redeployment
const triggers = [methodResource.id, integration.id, many more]; 


// add deployment with trigger
const devDeployment = new aws.apigateway.Deployment('devDeployment', {
    restApi: api.id,
    triggers: {
        redeployment: 
            pulumi.all(triggers)
                .apply((triggers) => JSON.stringify(triggers))
                .apply(toJSON => crypto.createHash('sha1').update(toJSON).digest('hex')),
    },
});
```

That trigger works for changes and additions. Whenever I add a new method, or change an existing one, a re-deployment of the api happens. But **when I remove a previously defined method, no deployment gets triggered**.

How can i change my trigger so that it also fires, when i remove a method?